# Excel VBA not returning the ObjectThemeColor?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

I have a chart `Series` (referenced by the variable `sr`). If I execute

```
sr.Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
```

(=6), then I get

```
? sr.Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor
  0
```

How is this possible?

The line assigning `msoThemeColorAccent2` does its job, i.e., the color is changed correctly.

PS: This is a more specific question, derived from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19395760/2707864).

Comment: I could be wrong but if my memory is not failing me then yes, this is a bug. You can write to `.ObjectThemeColor` of the series but not read from it. It will always give you `0`... Let me double check just to be sure...

Comment: I couldn't find any article per se but was able to replicate the issue on 4 different charts. You can try this in the immediate window to check `?Activechart.seriescollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - If this is a bug, then I would post it as an answer, as it appears to be **the** answer. PS: I have also obtained -2 as a return value, but this is simply a detail. PS2: your suggestion for the immediate window is essentially the same as what I posted in the question.

Comment: The reason I didn't post it as an answer is because I could find any reliable link which can confirm that it is a bug even though I was able to replicate it :)

Comment: I have sent emails to few Excel MVPs asking them for their opinion on this one. Let's see if anyone responds...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - +1 to your comment, for requiring documentation to back an answer *for the negative*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the bug in 32-bit Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013. I then reported it to the person at Microsoft who maintains the bug tracker.

My guess is that this will receive a "won't fix" type of response, but perhaps they will get to it in the next version of Excel.

Comment: @sancho.s: I see that you have finally accepted an answer :) BTW, Brad is an Excel-MVP and he is one of the few people whom I hold in high regard :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - As said, the answer allows for burying the question in its grave (name: Bug). In the end, it is **the** answer. Exactly what I look for in SO.

Comment: @sancho.s: Yup I agree. it is definitely an answer :)

Comment: The bug also affects Excel 2011 (Macintosh). Initial feedback from Microsoft is that the bug was reported in Excel 2010, but not resolved at that time. They will revisit the issue, a good response considering that the feature has never worked and doesn't prevent people from getting their work done.